# make loop in jquery lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, lightbox

Hello i'm trying to create loop for image gallery in jquery lightbox plugin http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/. (when it reaches the last image show next button for first image, or when it is showing first image, display prev button for last image) So far I have found that i need to change these lines :

```
        // Show the prev button, if not the first image in set
        if ( settings.activeImage != 0 ) {
            if ( settings.fixedNavigation ) {
                $('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev').css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnPrev + ') left 15% no-repeat' })
                    .unbind()
                    .bind('click',function() {
                        settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage - 1;
                        _set_image_to_view();
                        return false;
                    });
            } else {
                // Show the images button for Next buttons
                $('#lightbox-nav-btnPrev').unbind().hover(function() {
                    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnPrev + ') left 15% no-repeat' });
                },function() {
                    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'transparent url(' + settings.imageBlank + ') no-repeat' });
                }).show().bind('click',function() {
                    settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage - 1;
                    _set_image_to_view();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }

        // Show the next button, if not the last image in set
        if ( settings.activeImage != ( settings.imageArray.length -1 ) ) {
            if ( settings.fixedNavigation ) {
                $('#lightbox-nav-btnNext').css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnNext + ') right 15% no-repeat' })
                    .unbind()
                    .bind('click',function() {
                        settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage + 1;
                        _set_image_to_view();
                        return false;
                    });
            } else {
                // Show the images button for Next buttons
                $('#lightbox-nav-btnNext').unbind().hover(function() {
                    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'url(' + settings.imageBtnNext + ') right 15% no-repeat' });
                },function() {
                    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'transparent url(' + settings.imageBlank + ') no-repeat' });
                }).show().bind('click',function() {
                    settings.activeImage = settings.activeImage + 1;
                    _set_image_to_view();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
```

My knowledge in jquery is basic, so maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether lightbox supports cycle or not. By the way you can do the same thing using two methods.

**Method 1**: Use [Fancy Box Plugin](http://fancybox.net/)

In this also your image will be opened in popup and it also support cycle, as you wished. It is highly customizable.

**Method 2**: Use [Jquery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) along with lightbox
This plugin support cycle feature.

I'll **prefer Method 1** for such implementions, but if lightbox is mandatory for you to use, you can go with method 2, rather than writing your own code, which may contain errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For pop up loop the magnifix popup [this](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) way:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

  console.log(i);

  $('.popup-gallery' + i).magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true,
      navigateByImgClick: true,
      preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
    },
    image: {
      tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
      titleSrc: function(item) {
        return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by PNG City Builder</small>';
      }
    }
  });

}
```